# Quiero crear un servidor DNS a partir de no-ip

Tags: apache, apache2, dns, dominio

Me gustaría crear un subdominio en una raspberry, tengo ya un dominio que apunta a mi raspberry (ejemplo.sytes.net), como tengo varias páginas web y proyectos me gustaría crear un subdominio (proy1.ejemplo.sytes.net) para cada una de ellas, lo poco que me permite no-ip no es suficiente para crear mis subdominios, y me gustaría saber como puedo hacerlo montando un servidor bind(DNS) en mi raspberry a partir del dominio principal (ejemplo.sytes.net), ya que llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas y no consigo nada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres es hacerte cargo de un subdominio y es algo por lo que cobran.

Yo me iría al servidor de no-ip mas barato y las daría de alta allí. 
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-do-i-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain

Answer (score 0):

Quiero suponer que tienes alguna distro linux corriendo LAMP ¿verdad? primero debes crear host virtuales (vhost) con apache y después crear los registros en el servidor de DNS yo te recomendaría utilizar bind9.

Con esas opciones ya podrás apuntar subdominios sin problema.

Saludos

Comment: Te seria posible proporcionar un [mcve] en tu respuesta? Eso seria muy bueno.

Comment: Puedes tener varios sitios alojados en tu servidor, la idea es utilizar vhost para que cada sitio tenga su propio subdominio ve a la ruta /etc/apache2/sites-available/ crea un archivo con el nombre del sitio, después ingresa estos datos suponiendo que la IP es 172.20.30.40 y el puerto 80: Listen 80

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName prueba.example.org
</VirtualHost>